# Django rest framework email validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to validate email id if already exists in the User model before registration

This is my serializer with validation

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate_email(self,attrs):
            email=attrs['email']
            print email
            if email:
                    emailset = Q(email__icontains=email)
                    emailres = User.objects.filter(emailset)
                    if emailres:
                            msg = _('The email address is already taken')
                            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
                    else:
                            return attars
```

It is throwing error "TypeError:string indices must be integers"

```
 email=attrs['email']
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I Guess you have upgraded or using DRF 3.x, so there is no more `attrs` dict but the value instead. See [field-level-validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)

More over there is already a [UniqueValidator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator). So I think you can just do:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    #...
    email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
```